# How can I implement the share the app before uploading to Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have sharing button of app. By this button I want to share my app with my friends. But now its in developing phase. I know after uploading this APK to market I will get link. Before uploading APK, how can I show the link?
I do not want to update my APK after getting link. Is there any way?

Comment: What about initially publishing to alpha/beta channel of Play Store (and can confine access initially to specific users)?

Comment: thanks john , but if i   use alpha/beta channel so can i remove my this apk from there . because i have to implement  lot of function in my current apk .

Comment: you don't have to promote (to production) builds you publish to alpha/beta channels.  You can continue to deploy there until you're ready to promote (frequent setup is that every green build in your CI env is published to alpha).

Comment: or else i can use this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mypackagename&hl=en?

Comment: it will same above same link  right?

Comment: anyway thank you so much "John" for your suggestion

Comment: For this u can use the DropBox and share the apk link

Comment: Thanks Bahu . i want only google play link . is it ok if i will use this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mypackagename&hl=en?

Answer (score 2):

For Sharing Application you need link which can open playstore with your application, so for that you need to apply below logic which will help you.

```
final String appPackageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
      String strAppLink = ""; 

try 
{
    strAppLink = "market://details?id=" + appPackageName;
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) 
{
    strAppLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName;
}

// Now From Here You Can Use strAppLink For Sharing Purpose
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Vicky . but my question is that after live of application  the link  will be same ?https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName?

Comment: Yes this link will work anytime before publishing app this will open playstore which no app found and after publishing app on playstore it will open app, so this link will work exactly as you want after publish the app.

Comment: Enjoy Your Coding

Comment: how can i do same for my flutter app

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Jugaad (Makeshifter) for it.

1] Create a account in Bit.ly

2] bit.ly allows you to make custom shorted links

3] find a custom link which nobody has used (Just write anything randomly)

ex. "https://bit.l y/m yappsgdgnx" (just search this link so to know this is used or not.)
(giving spaces due to SOF's guidelines)

4] Use that unused link in your app

5] When you will get your app link then just short it naming that unused link